# Typescript React error - parameter 'inside' implicitly has an 'any' type using Context

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a `context.tsx` file which would be used to share data across components. Currently I am getting the error:

```
parameter 'inside' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

I am sure defining the array as any is not good practice, but don't know any other way?

So far my code is:

**context.tsx**

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export const DataContext = React.createContext({
  data: '',
  other: '',
  item: [] as any
});

interface Iresponse {
  userId: number,
  id: number,
  title: string,
  completed: boolean,
};

export const DataProvider: React.FunctionComponent = ({children}) => {
  const [data] = React.useState<string>('Example text 1);
  const [other] = React.useState<string>('Example text 2');
  const [item, setItem] = React.useState<Iresponse[]>([]);
  const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';

  // Global data axios call
  useEffect (
    () => {
      let mounted = true;
      const loadData = async (): Promise<any> => {
        try {
          const response = await axios (url);
          if (mounted) {
          setItem (response.data);
          console.log('data mounted')
          }
        } catch (err) {
          console.log (err);
        }
      };
      loadData ();
      return () => {
        mounted = false;
        console.log ('cleaned');
      };
    },
    [url]
  );
  
  return (
    <DataContext.Provider value={{data, other, item}}>
      {children}
    </DataContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

in the other component consuming the context.

```
import React from 'react';
import {DataContext} from '../../context/Context';

interface Iresponse {
    userId: number,
    id: number,
    title: string,
    completed: boolean,
  };

const Comp1: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
    const {data, other, item} = React.useContext(DataContext);
    
    const mappInner: React.FunctionComponent<Iresponse[]> = () => {
        return (
            item.map(inside => {
                <ul key={inside.id}>
                    <li>{inside.title}</li>
                </ul>
            })
        )
    }

    return (
        <>
        <h1>{other}</h1>
        <p>{data}</p>
        {mappInner}
        </>
    ) 
}

export default Comp1;
```

Any idea's?

Answer (score 0):

If the inside object has only the id and title properties as we can see, then you should define them at your interface like this:

```
export interface Inside {
  id: string;
  title: string;
}
```

and then pass the type to your parameter:

```
 item.map((inside:Inside) => ...
```

Or better, define your item in the props interface:

```
export const DataContext = React.createContext({
  data: '',
  other: '',
  item: {id:string, title:string}[] 
});
```

Comment: None of those solutions actually work. If you pass in the interface to the map function you get `A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.ts(2355)
`

Comment: Sorry I was really tired, edited with the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like I had to define a type for the context and some default values:

```
interface Iresponse {
  userId: number,
  id: number,
  title: string,
  completed: boolean,
};

interface ContextData {
  item: Iresponse[],
  data: string,
  other: string
}

export const DataContext = React.createContext<ContextData>({
  item: [],
  data: '',
  other: '',
});
```

then just map over in the consumer:

```
 {item.map(inner => {
      return (
        <p>{inner.title}</p>
      )
 })}
```